# Java Apache POI (Excel) Convert Data in Sheet to Table

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I'm trying to put together a report for a customer using Apache POI and I was getting on well with it, but the last major step is taking the existing data and putting it in table objects. I've been learning as I go but this last part escapes me, and the file is generated without any errors in Eclipse but Windows complains about it being corrupt so I don't get any useful messages to help me figure it out. At this point I'm not entirely sure if I'm even doing it in the correct order, so here's the situation:

- I need to pull down data from a SQL database; process it and (depending on one piece of the data) put it in a particular tab in the spreadsheet (all working fine).
- Each of those tabs contains essentially the same table with the same columns (16) but differing numbers of rows.
- I need a grand totals row at the bottom which can update dynamically depending on filter options, the easiest option seemed to be putting the data into Table objects and in previous Excel macro-based versions of this report that worked ok, but building the thing in Java is a lot cleaner for various reasons.

The current iteration of the code generates the sheet fine and leaves me with the data in the correct rows and columns, I just need to know how I can take that data and put it into Table objects and the documentation hasn't been much help there. I'm not actually sure if I should be generating the table objects at the end when I have all the data or if I should be generating them first and having the code populate the table instead of the base sheet (and I don't know how either of those is best accomplished). I've found some example code for creating and populating a table with basic integers and I tried to modify it to suit, but I'm not having much luck. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong here I'd appreciate it!

```
    for (int sheetIndex = 1; sheetIndex < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++)
    {
        XSSFSheet current = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);

        //Create 
        XSSFTable table = current.createTable();
        table.setDisplayName(current.getSheetName());
        CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        //Style configurations
        //CTTableStyleInfo style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();   //Doesn't seem to work?
        //style.setName("TableStyleMedium2");
        //style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
        //style.setShowRowStripes(true);

        //Set which area the table should be placed in
        CellReference lastCell = new CellReference(current.getLastRowNum(),current.getRow(0).getLastCellNum());
        AreaReference reference = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0),lastCell);
        cttable.setRef(reference.formatAsString());
        cttable.setId(1);
        cttable.setName("Test");
        cttable.setTotalsRowCount(1);
        cttable.setTotalsRowShown(true);

        CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
        columns.setCount(16);
        CTTableColumn column;
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        for(int i=0; i<16; i++) { //16 used for testing purposes
            //Create column
            column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
            column.setName(formatter.formatCellValue(current.getRow(0).getCell(i)));
            column.setId(i+1);
            //Create row
            row = current.createRow(i);
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) { //4 used for testing purposes
                //Create cell
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(formatter.formatCellValue(current.getRow(j).getCell(i)));
            }
        }
    }
```